AWS - Collect events globally via CloudTrail
I have a CloudTrail trail setup - it is multi-regional, and it writes logs to the bucket licated within the same region (trail is in us-east-1, and cloudtrail bucket is in us-east-1, too)
I did setup an EvenBridge rule with event pattern capturing all the events going through CloudTrail (AWS API Call via CloudTrail, with eventSource set as { prefix: "" }) - to summarize, it should capture all the events I could see in CloudTrail, in EventBridge. I also set SQS as a trigger.
Everything works fine! Except that i can see events in SQS from us-east-1 region only. Documentation says, I must have trail S3 in the same region as my multi-region trail, so I can capture events from every region.
Am i missing something? Any help will be appreciated!
I expect to capture events from all the regions in a single place

I encountered this as well, it seems like there is no 1-1 match between what CloudTrail logs and what it sends to EventBridge. Also, it's very frustrating to debug these events.
